# Shape Deleting in Powerpoint through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, shapes

I am currently trying to delete a shape on a slide in excel and replace it with a new one. The weird part is, I have achieved this on slide 6 and then try to replicate the process on slide 4; however, it does not delete the shape it merely pastes the new shape over the top. The code I have is shown below; NOTE: Both slides have a similar format, 2 title textboxes and then the shape. The ONLY difference is slide 6 has 2 title text boxes and **1 sub title box** and then the shape.

```
Set Financials = Sheet20.Range("A17:C21")
Set Assumptions = Sheet45.Range("A1:C5")

'Choose slide number

Set FinSlide = PPTPrez.Slides(6)
Set AssumSlide = PPTPrez.Slides(4)

'If there is a table in powerpoint slide, delete the table

For Pic1Count = AssumSlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    If AssumSlide.Shapes(Pic1Count).Type = msoPicture Then
        AssumSlide.Shapes(Pic1Count).Delete
    End If
Next

For PicCount = FinSlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    If FinSlide.Shapes(PicCount).Type = msoPicture Then
        FinSlide.Shapes(PicCount).Delete
    End If
Next
```

So the second part of this code works (the FinSlide); however, the AssumSlide does not. Any thoughts or help?

Comment: Can you add a `Debug.Print` statement inside your loop to test what the shape type is? `msoPicture` returns a value of 13.

Comment: This does not output anything, its just a blank row..

Comment: `Debug.Print AssumSlide.Shapes(Pic1Count).Type` - right before your `If` statement

Comment: I did that... didnt look at the output because I noticed it worked? Just tried it 5 times over and now it is deleting the picture.. I have not changed the code at all and it works even if I take the debug out again. Weird..